# Need help on a calculation for a gravel pit

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> I have a gravel pit $70$ inches in diameter on the inside. I want to make the pit $4$ inches deep in gravel. The bags come in $0.5$ cubic feet.

I can't even figure out how many cubic feet. How many bags would I need to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: **Hint**: can you find the volume of the pit (in cubic feet) and then divide that volume by $0.5$ (how many times does a single $0.5$ cubic foot bag go into the pit)?

Comment: @Hint 70 x 4? I have no idea. It's been 20 years since I was in algebra. A link to something to help me figure it out and I'll give it a shot. :D

Comment: If the pit has a *diameter*, then it is likely a cylindrical pit. How do you find the volume of a cylinder?

Comment: @MikePierce V=πr2h so  3.14 x (35 x 35) x 4  = 15386 \ .5 = 30772  Couldn't be right. What am I doing wrong? Got this from here http://www.virtualnerd.com/tutorials/?id=PreAlg_11_01_0017

Comment: Check your units. The pit's measurements are in inches, while the bag's are in feet. You need to do some converting to common units.

Comment: @MikePierce 15386 cu inches = 8.9039352 cu feet. So 8.9 x .5 = 4.45 bags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Get the volume of the pit:** I guess the gravel pit is supposed to be in cylindric shape. The volume of a cylinder is (as in most geometric 3D-objects) given by

$$\text{volume}_{\text{cyl}}=(\text{area of base}) \cdot \text{height}.$$

The base is a circle which has area $r^2\pi$ where $r$ is the radius (which is half the diameter). Your height is 4 inches. Plug this in and you have the volume of the gravel pit in cubic inches you have to fill.

Computing that yields

> $\text{volume}_{\text{cyl}}=(35 ~\mathrm{in})^2\pi\cdot 4~\mathrm{in}\approx 15393.80~\mathrm{in}^3.$

**2. Get the volume of 1 bag:** This is already given in the question. But you need to have the same units, so you might want to switch from $0.5$ cubic feet to $$\text{volume}_{\text{bag}}=864 ~\mathrm{in}^3.$$

**3. Get the amount of bags:** This is easily done by

$$\text{amount of bags} = \frac{\text{volume}_{\text{cyl}}}{\text{volume}_{\text{bag}}}.$$

Computing that yields

> $\text{amount of bags} = \frac{15393.80~\mathrm{in}^3}{864 ~\mathrm{in}^3}\approx 17.82$

**4. The aftermath:** If the number you get from 3. is not an integer, you need to round that number up to the next integer since you can't buy fractions of bags. This means you'll need

> $\lceil 17.82 \rceil=18$

bags.

Comment: See [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16341/what-to-do-when-other-users-answer-low-quality-questions).

Comment: Apart from the fact that I understand that it doesn't feel nice to be interrupted in your ongoing explanation in the comments - I'm sorry, but I don't really get your point from posting that link. If that's the explanation for not voting on my answer and encouraging others to do the same then that's completely fine. I'll try to explain in short what happened: Like yourself, I wanted to start giving hints in the comments, but wrote a little bit more than you did. Shortly before being finished, you posted your comment and posting mine became pointless. *(cont.~>)*

Comment: *(~>cont.)* My situation then: 1) I didn't want to throw away what I wrote. 2) I realized my comment is almost a complete answer. 3) I felt like my answer would be a nice alternative to the one that has already been given. *Conclusion:* I formatted my comment and made it into an answer. **I didn't mean to sneak reputation or compromise your help.** I just wanted to increase the overall quality of this question by providing another answer which at that point basically was laying around "on my desk".

Answer (score -1):

For ease u can do conversions from inches to feet and proceed by formula of volume is π rsquare h. And then calculate a 0.5 cubic feet bag takes

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Please see [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to nicely format your post, and you should also probably read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16341/what-to-do-when-other-users-answer-low-quality-questions?lq=1).